# Hashcodes are appearing different for two user defined objects of same type

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I have a program to search the key to print the values from a hashmap. But my inputs to the Key and Values are objects that are user defined.Now when I'm equating input `key` with `key1`  why are the hashcodes of the Objects `key` and `key1` in the program appearing different, although the return type is same,ie. `NameInit`, where the hashcodes of the `String str="abc"` and `abc` are returned equal? How to check the equality of `key` and `key1` in the program? I tried `Objects.equals(key,key1)` after type-casting to `Object` class, but still did not work.I have seen questions of similar kind like in [this question][1] that discusses about the hashcode equality, but then again how to do the equality of these objects as in my example. Kindly help.
    
**NameInit** Class

```
public class NameInit {
String name;
public NameInit(String name)
 {
  this.name = name;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString(){
  return name;
  }    
}
```

**PlaceAndAddInit**

```
public class PlaceAndAddInit {

String place;
int value;
public PlaceAndAddInit(String place,int val) {
   this.place = place;
   this.value= val;
    }
@Override
public String toString(){
  return place+" "+value;
   }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  HashMap h = new HashMap();
  System.out.println("Limit: ");
  int limit = scan.nextInt();
  for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
     h.put(new NameInit(scan.next()), new PlaceAndAddInit(scan.next(), 
     scan.nextInt()));
    }
  System.out.println("Enter a key to search the value: ");//
  NameInit key= new NameInit(scan.next());//asks for a input from the user to fetch the values
  Set s = h.entrySet();
  Iterator<NameInit> itr = s.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext())
     {
       Map.Entry<NameInit,PlaceAndAddInit> me = (Map.Entry) itr.next();
       NameInit key1 =me.getKey();
       if(key.equals(key1)){// this never happens with this code as key and key1 holds different hashcodes. So how do I achieve the equality.
           System.out.println(me.getValue());
            }
      }
    }
  }
```

> **Edit:** I tried to obtain equality by `equals` method to which I discovered that hashcodes of `key1` and `key` are different. Understanding the reason behind this is the purpose of my question.

Comment: It is not clear on your exact problem. And you should show the implementation of `NameInit`, at least for `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not overriding `hashCode()` so the default is used. In the default implementation, `key` and `key1` will have different hashCode values and they will not be equal even if you think they should be. So the solution is to override the `hashCode` and `equals` method if you want to be able to compare those objects.

To answer your question:

> Edit: I tried to obtain equality by equals method to which I
>   discovered that hashcodes of key1 and key are different. Understanding
>   the reason behind this is the purpose of my question.

If you don't provide overrides to `equals` and `hashCode`, they will get inherited from `Object`. And here's how they look for `Object`:

```
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

Therefore, 2 objects will only be equal when they are `==` which means that they point to precisely the same memory location. In your example, it is not the case. `hashCode` is native so can't show you the source code.

Here's more to read:

[Google search about hashCode and equals](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=effective%20java%20equals%20hashcode&oq=effective%20java%20equals%20hashcode&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30k1.11008.11008.0.11187.1.1.0.0.0.0.115.115.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.114.DOXZwzjUjro)

Comment: `@Override

        public int hashCode(){

            return Objects.hash(name);
        }
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            NameInit n =(NameInit) o;
            return Objects.equals(n.name, name);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

`Objects.equals` is implemented like this:

```
return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
```

You see, it is basically calling `a`'s `equals` method, ***not*** the `hashcode` method. No matter how `hashcode` is implemented `Objects.equals` returns false when `a.equals(b)` returns false. It has nothing to do with the `hashcode` method.

So to fix this, simply override the `equals` method. This is a simple implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.hashcode() == obj.hashcode();
}
```

Also, if you want to find the value of a key in the hash map, call the `get` method on the hash map and it will do it for you in O(1) time. No need for such an inefficient approach with O(n) time.